# ngOptions: Removing value types in select

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs version 1.5. the ng-option is generating values with types like this

```
<select name="type" ng-model="type" ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in Providers">
    <option label="Provider 1" value="string:prov1">Provider1</option>
    <option label="Provider 2" value="string:prov2">Provider2</option>
    <option label="Provider 3" value="string:prov3">Provider3</option>
</select>
```

How to fix ng-options so in value it don't generate type of value like string: or number: or object:

Comment: Why do you care? What should only matter is the value inside the model, not the value in the DOM.

Comment: was using version 1.2.x and there I was submitting using $('#form').serialize() method of jquery :S

Comment: That's a bad idea. Why don't you use $http, and post the model rather than the serialized version of the form? You're not using angularJS as intended, and are thus hitting walls. Note that angular has https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike, which allows serializing an object just like JQuery would.

Answer (score 1):

Use "track by" consider the following example
Controller js:

```
$scope.selOptions=[ 
    {'id':1,'val':'Value 1'},
    {'id':1,'val':'Value 3'},
];
```

Html:

```
   <select data-placeholder="Select Value" ng-model="selectedValue"     
       ng-options="item.id as item.val for item in selOptions track by item.id"  class="form-control"> 
   <option value="">-- Select value --</option>
   </select>
```

The above example will not print types "String:" Or "Number:" and it will not generate empty option